# @BeanParam gives exception A message body reader for Java class was not found

Tags: rest, jersey

I am trying to make a jersey based web service. In this if i take input params using @FormParam it works fine:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_HTML, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
@Path("/registeruser")
public Response registerUser(@FormParam ("email") String email,@FormParam ("name") String name ){
    System.out.println("Inside register device");
    System.out.println("registered" + email);
    return null;
}
```

but when I try using @BeanParam it does not works and gives me an exception

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_HTML, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
@Path("/registeruser")
public Response registerUser(@BeanParam UserForm userForm ){
    System.out.println("Inside register device");
    service.registerUser(userForm);
    System.out.println("registered" + userForm.getEmail());
    return null;
}
```

A message body reader for Java class com.stc.dms.forms.UserForm, and Java type class com.stc.dms.forms.UserForm, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.

Comment: 1) why are you accepting a request body for a GET request? 2) what jersey version are you using? 3) have you been able to get @BeanParam to work in other instance, say with some @QueryParams?

Comment: No i have not been able to do it. Its POST request only by mistake i entered GET

Comment: Can you try it right now. Make a different GET method, with a bean with just a couple @QueryParams.

Comment: I just tried it with @QueryParam and it works fine bt i dont want to keep adding parameters like this. I want to Object as input

Comment: Why are you consuming so many different media types? Have to tried to limit it to APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED, and making sure the on the client the Content-Type is set to application/x-www-form-urlencded?

Comment: Yes I tried to do that even...It dosnt help as weel

Comment: have you annotated the fields of the POJO class with the other parameter annotations like PathParam, QueryParam, HeaderParam, MatrixParam etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `@BeanParam` to pass an object as input. Just pass it like this :

```
@POST
@Path("register")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response registerUser(UserForm dto) {
  // ...
}
```

Just make sure to include the libraries for producing/consuming json. If the client is in javascript you don't need anything else (just use `JSON.stringify()` on your form object), for the server add some json libraries such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

EDIT :
If you want to stick with `@BeanParam`, take a look at this tutorial [here](http://javatech-blog.blogspot.it/2014/08/bean-parameter-example.html). Basically it seems that you don't need to specify the mediatype, as Jersey will handle that for you.